# asp.net razor adding autocomplete value to html text box

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor

I have a subject box in razor form which adds default wording too. But I want to add what the user picks in the drop down box. the drop down box id is CustomFieldValue8. How would i do this ? I am new to razor. This is an autocomplete textbox if that matters, Jquery.

```
<td colspan="2">



        @LangStrings.Subject<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subject, new { @Value = "Specification Change Request", @style = "width:30%" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject)
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope these pages could help:

http://jqueryextensions.codeplex.com/

http://mvcautocomplete.codeplex.com/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/11/13/autocompletion-textbox-in-mvc-using-jquery.aspx

http://carlhoerberg.com/how-to-use-jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-aspnet

http://autocompletedotnet.codeplex.com/documentation#Asp.Net%20MVC

For example if you use the last autocomplete, and download the dll, you could use the autocomplete simply in your view like this:

```
@Html.AutoCompleteTextBox("country", 
                 new Uri("/Countries/SearchByFirstLetters", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), 
                 "Name")
```